# How to fix Grub loader that hangs and waits for user with read only root partition?

Tags: boot, grub2, root, read-only

I am trying to create a set of Ubuntu 12.04 slave systems that have a read only root partition and a small read/write partition mounted for a single user.  These systems will be used for a short job processing and I don't want anything to change except in that small read/write user space.

We have successfully done this before and I have everything setup for version 12.04 but I am having some issues with the Grub loader.  If the root partition is marked as read-only in `/etc/fstab` the system does not automatically go past the grub loader.  I can manually get past it by hitting enter but I don't want to wait for the user prompt.  If the root partition is setup as read/write it gets past the grub loader with no problem.

The other weird thing on this is that it seems to be an issue only on the second and subsequent reboots to the system. I can change the partition to read-only and reboot once with no problem but on the second reboot it hangs at the Grub Loader prompt.

How to fix the hanging grub loader that doesn't wait for a user interaction at prompt?

Comment: is the /boot folder on the root partition? Might be best if not. You should run `sudo update-grub` after you've edited fstab I think.

Comment: Yes the system is setup with a single partition with /boot on the root partition.  I have run update-grub several times while the root partiton is mounted as read/write with no change.